# JavaScript arrow functions

Tags: javascript, lambda, callback, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

I have seen some code that looks like this:

```
function printErr(err) {
    console.error(err)
}
request.on('error', err => printErr)
```

How does that work? I have spent hours trying to figure it out and searching everywhere for it. I know that printErr is an object with a function that is being returned but what is the mechanism that lets it put the err parameter into the function and call it?

I am thinking along the lines of:

```
function foo(callback){
    callback()
}

request.on('error', err => foo)
```

But how does it get the arguments?

Comment: It should not work. `.on` typically requires a function, whose return value is disregarded; `err => printErr` is a function that just returns another function. There is nothing that will run `printErr` there. Are you sure you copied the example correctly? Can you link to the source where you saw it?

Comment: You are correct. I think it was just a mistake in the code. I did copy the example correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short hand for the arrow function. Whenever there is only `one argument` we can call it even without `parentheses` and `=>` represents the `return`. When there is only a single line `return` we can explicitly use `=>` for returning rather then using return.

```js
var a=e=>"hey";
console.log(a())
```

This is same as the above

```js
var a=(e)=>{return "hey"};
console.log(a())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was confused at first but it was because the code I was analyzing was mistaken.

to simplify

```js
function print(data) {
    console.log(data)
}

const foo = [1,2,3,4]

foo.forEach(x => print) // will not print and just return undefined.
foo.forEach(x => print(x)) // will print correctly
```

Comment: Note that also `foo.forEach(print)` will work as well.